# Burninate [achievements] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

There's a tag [achievements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/achievements).

It's description is

> Successfull accomplishment, especially by means of exertion, skill, practice, or perseverance.

It looks like a very meta tag for me. Should it be burninated?

Answer (score 11):

I don't think that's a meta tag. It doesn't describe some quality of the question, like [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective) or [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner).  Most of the questions tagged [achievements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/achievements) are about implementing achievements in games or other social applications. The tag might need a clean-up to close questions that are off-topic, but I don't think it should be burninated.

Comment: Achievement Get! Save the achievement tag.

Comment: The tag wiki could also do with a cleanup to match.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it's not a meta tag. But is it useful?

- You can't be an expert in "achievements"
- It doesn't help with searching more than title/body text
- It makes no meaningful categorization

Comment: I'm not a game programming expert, but it's simple to imagine a good use case for the tag: integrating achievements with a platform like steam or xbl or [insert name of sony plaform here]. You can be ask meaningful questions about this, and you can also be an expert in integrating a game with such a platform, so I think the tag should not just be burninated. It might be more appropriate to make platform-specific tags though, such as `steam-achievements` etc.

Comment: @l4mpi Platform-specific tags would be great, as long as there are enough questions using them.